# The app is freezing for a little bit when using Retrofit with RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-android

**JSON**

```
[
   {
      "countryName":"..."
   },
   {
      "countryName":"..."
   },
   {
      "countryName":"..."
   } //etc... to 195 countries
]
```

**Interface**

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("GetCountries.php")
    Single<List<CountryModel>> getCountries();

}
```

**Code**

```
new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()).build().create(RetrofitInterface.class).getCountries().doOnSuccess(countryModels - > {
    for (CountryModel item: countryModels) {
        Chip chip = new Chip(requireContext());
        chip.setText(item.getCountryName());
        fragmentCountriesBinding.fragmentCountriesChipGroupMain.addView(chip);
    }
}).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new SingleObserver < List < CountryModel >> () {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull List < CountryModel > countryModels) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
        
    }
});
```

I'm trying to add 195 countries to the `ChipGroup` but the app is freezing for a little bit during adding the chips, Firstly the code inside the `doOnSuccess` method was in the `onSuccess` method but the app was freezing for a little bit, So the code has been moved to `doOnSuccess` method but I get this message Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I'm new with RxJava, Any solutions?

Comment: mmm I dont work with Rx, but maybe you could use a new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) and use the post method to populate and show the chips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgot to set scheduler on what it should be subscribed.
By default, an Observable and the chain of operators that you apply to it will do its work, and will notify its observers, on the same thread on which its Subscribe method is called.
so if you call it from the main thread it will be executed on the main thread. It's the reason why your app is freezing, because you make network request on the main thread, responsible for UI.

To fix it just set another scheduler with subscribeOn method:

```
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

So in your case, it should looks something like this:

```
getCountries().doOnSuccess(countryModels - > {
    ...
}).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // Asynchronously subscribes  to the observable on the IO scheduler.
  .subscribe(

    ...

)
```

Detailed documentation:
https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html

Also the article that can be helpful to understand thread handling in RxJava:
https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-rxjava-subscribeon-and-observeon-744b0c6a41ea

Comment: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. I tried to skip the problem by doing this but the same thing app freezing a little bit. Look at the image https://ibb.co/kSjrgQ4

Comment: yeah, I see. In your case you add a lot of views at the one moment in onSuccess. IN the comment you mentioned about 27 countries. You have inner cycle:
For 0 to 50 
  For (CountryModel chip : countrymodels)
So, if countrtymodels.size =27 then you add 27*50 = 1350 items to array.
You can check it, just log chips.size value in the onSuccess method.
If it really greater than 1000 you create a view and add it to view hierarchy, it's a very big operation to create and add 1350 views . In this case you should think about using of RecyclerView to display a list of items.

Comment: RecyclerView is optimized to work with big arrays of data. More details about Recycler view usage you can find in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Yes, I already was thinking of switching to RecyclerView and using Chips only for the small data (1 to 10 chips).

Comment: I cannot accept your answer because I lost the SE19 account. But I'll give you the bounty after 6 hours. Thank You